# Maps using chilemapas

Tags: maps, polygon

I’m trying to do a map of five counties (comunas) of Chile by using the chilemapas package, by I haven’t been capable of showing the polygons that are in my working dataset on the map of the streets of these five counties.

Basically, I have a data like this:

```
colnames(original_data) <- c("region","comuna","project","investment","sector","latitude","longitude")
```

And what I would like is to have one street map of the five counties with one pin for each project and that the color of this pin is different for each economic sector. At the same time, I would like to have a circle around the pin and that the size of this circle depends on the investment amount of the project.
I was able to join this data with the space data of chilemapas and build an interactive map using leaflet.

```
# Map.
leaflet(data=join_data, options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 5, maxZoom = 15)) %>% 
    addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
    addMarkers(lat= join_data$latitude, lng= join_data$longitude, popup = join_data $investment) %>% 
    setView(lng=-70.7, lat=-33.2 , zoom=10) %>% 
    addTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(data = join_data, lng = ~ longitude, lat = ~ latitude, radius = 5, 
                     color = ~ sector,
                     clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

However, this map just shows the location of the projects, nothing else.

I also tried this, but I only get the polygons, the map isn’t shown.

```
ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = join_data, aes(x=latitude, y = longitude, group = comuna), fill="grey", alpha=0.3) +
    geom_point(data=original_data, aes(x= latitude, y= longitude, size= investment, color=investment)) +
    scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,12)) +
    scale_color_viridis(trans="log") +
    theme_void() + 
    coord_map()
```

Anyone has any ideas on how can I solve this?